# No option to hibernate/shutdown in GNOME 3?

Tags: linux, gnome, gnome-panel

I have installed Fedora 15 Alpha with GNOME 3. Everything is working fine. However, I can't see any option to hibernate or shutdown.

In the top panel when I click my user name, I only have one option and that is to suspend. Normally I like to hibernate or shutdown. And I can't see any option of what to do when I close my netbook. Normally, I prefer to hibernate.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and *Suspend* will change to *Power off*.

Comment: Thanks Patches. That worked for the shutdown. However, I still need to hibernate. Is there any option to hibernate. And is there any option to hibernate when I close the network. Thanks.

Comment: @ant:  AFAICT GNOME 3 doesn't offer a way to hibernate.  You can try sending the cross-desktop Hibernate dbus command by running this on a  terminal:  `dbus-send --session --dest=org.freedesktop.PowerManagement --type=method_call /org/freedesktop/PowerManagement org.freedesktop.PowerManagement.Hibernate`

Comment: You can install the 'gnome-tweak-tool' that has advanced settings for setting for the power management. That solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: This is reason #3,459 why Linus Torvalds hates Gnome3.

Comment: Vice versa in the newer versions...

Answer (score 12):

Install following extension will add "Shutdown" and "Hibernate" to your menu:

```
yum install gnome-shell-extensions-alternative-status-menu
```

From:
http://mygeekopinions.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-add-shutdownhibernate-menus-in.html

Solution for Ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-alternative-status-menu
```

From http://www.noobslab.com/2011/10/status-menu-gnome-shell-extension-for.html

Solution for Debian (should also work in Ubuntu):

Install gnome-tweak-tool:

```
sudo aptitude install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Restart the gnome-shell (Alt-F2 and type "r", then return.) Then open gnome-tweak-tool and go to "Shell Extensions" and set the option "Alternative Status Menu Extension"

Answer (score 2):

I've googled for the answer too, but before I read any provided, I had an insight: just press the power button on your device, a menu will pop up.

Comment: Sadly, that menu doesn't offer the Hibernate option...

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to install "**gnome-tweak-tool**" (which you may already have) and then set the "**power button action**" in the "shell" options to "**Hibernate**", achieving the obvious. Not ideal, but it's a straight forward gui solution.

Comment: I can't seem to find this in `gnome-tweaks` (as this tool is named now) in Gnome 3.32, so maybe they removed the preference entirely?

Comment: @MatthijsKooijman I can't find it here on Ubuntu anymore either. So I guess they removed it, in good old Gnome tradition. I've installed a Gnome extension that adds a hibernate button next to the shutdown one instead.